# Suspend/Resume used to work on Ubuntu 16.04 but not anymore

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, suspend

I have a Dell XPS 13 (9350) dual-booting Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (kernel: 4.4.0-72-generic) and Windows 10.

Recently my attempts to suspend my laptop have become more of a hit or miss. Most of the time, after a suspend, the systems doesn't resume properly and boots up as if it was shut down not suspended.

This problem didn't exist a month or so ago. Any advice?

Comment: You should have older kernels at the advanced Ubuntu boot section in grub (at least one), try the older kernels to boot your system,  see if they work for you.

Comment: A few if us now have been affected by something that happened a month ago :(

Comment: @Ravexina I have the same problem, and it only just began recently. I've tried going back to previous kernel versions, but they don't fix the problem.